# Why does this limit equal $2\cdot f'(x)$?

Tags: real-analysis, limits

Consider the limit $\lim\limits_{h\to 0}\dfrac{f(x_0 + nh)-f(x_0 + (n-2)h)}{h}$ with $f$ being differentiable at $x_0$ and $2 <n\in \mathbb{N}$. I think that this limit equals $2\cdot f'(x_0)$ (by trying it out for some polynomials) but when I tried to prove this I obtained the following:

$\lim\limits_{h\to 0}\dfrac{f(x_0 + nh)-f(x_0 + (n-2)h)}{h}=$

$=\lim\limits_{h\to 0}\dfrac{f(x_0 + nh)-f(x_0 + (n-2)h) + f(x_0)- f(x_0)}{h}=$

$=\lim\limits_{h\to 0}\dfrac{f(x_0 + nh)-f(x_0)}{h}-\lim\limits_{h\to 0}\dfrac{f(x_0 + (n-2)h)-f(x_0)}{h}$

$= f'(x_0) -f'(x_0) = 0$.

I suppose that I've made some mistake concerning the second term.

**Edit:** In addition to the answers, the mistake I made is to not use the correct definition of the derivative in assuming that $\lim\limits_{h\to 0}\dfrac{f(x_0 + nh)}{h} = f'(x_0)$ what is not the case! Analogously for the other term.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$\lim\limits_{h\to0}\dfrac{f\big(x_0+nh\big)-f\big(x_0 +(n-2)h\big)}{h}=$

$\begin{align}
&=\lim\limits_{h\to0}\dfrac{f\big(x_0+nh\big)-f\big(x_0+(n-2)h\big)+f(x_0)-f(x_0)}{h}=\\
&=\!\lim\limits_{h\to0}\!\dfrac{f(x_0+nh)-f(x_0)}{h}\!-\!\lim\limits_{h\to0}\!\dfrac{f\big(x_0+(n-2)h\big)-f(x_0)}{h}\!=\\\\
&=n\cdot\lim\limits_{h\to0}\dfrac{f(x_0+nh)-f(x_0)}{nh}\;+\\&\qquad\qquad\quad-(n-2)\cdot\lim\limits_{h\to0}\dfrac{f\big(x_0+(n-2)h\big)-f(x_0)}{(n-2)h}=\\\\
&=nf'(x_0)-(n-2)f'(x_0)=2f’(x_0)\;.
\end{align}$

Answer (score 0):

In the first term of the last line  you have to multiply numerator and denominator by $n$ and note that $nh \to 0$ as $ h \to 0$ So the first term is $nf'(x_0)$. Similarly, the second term is $(n-2)f'(x_0)$.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: we have

$$ \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{f(x_0+nh)-f(x_0)}{h} = n \cdot \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{f(x_0+nh)-f(x_0)}{nh}=n f'(x_0).$$

A similar argument gives that the second limit $=(n-2)f'(x_0).$